# Create-react-app Production build is not working in Android(4.0.x) Webview

Tags: android, reactjs, android-webview, webpack-2, babeljs

I am trying to open my React website in Android(4.0.x) Webview but it is giving me errors like

1) **E/Web Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word at vendor.*somehashcode*.js**

2) **E/Web Console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined at app.*somehashcode*.js**

my webpack.config.prod.js

```
// @remove-on-eject-begin
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */
// @remove-on-eject-end
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');
// const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const CriticalPlugin = require('webpack-plugin-critical').CriticalPlugin;
var LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
// var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const paths = require('./paths');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./prod-env');


// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
// const publicPath = paths.servedPath;
const publicPath = '/';
// Some apps do not use client-side routing with pushState.
// For these, "homepage" can be set to "." to enable relative asset paths.
const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
const publicUrl = publicPath.slice(0, -1);
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment('');

// Assert this just to be safe.
// Development builds of React are slow and not intended for production.
if (env['process.env'].NODE_ENV !== '"production"') {
  throw new Error('Production builds must have NODE_ENV=production.');
}

// Note: defined here because it will be used more than once.
const cssFilename = 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css';

// ExtractTextPlugin expects the build output to be flat.
// (See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/27)
// However, our output is structured with css, js and media folders.
// To have this structure working with relative paths, we have to use custom options.
const extractTextPluginOptions = shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths
  ? // Making sure that the publicPath goes back to to build folder.
    { publicPath: Array(cssFilename.split('/').length).join('../') }
  : {};

// This is the production configuration.
// It compiles slowly and is focused on producing a fast and minimal bundle.
// The development configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  // Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
  bail: true,
  // In production, we only want to load the polyfills and the app code.
  entry: {
    app:[require.resolve('bootstrap-loader'), require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],
    vendors : ['moment', 'moment-timezone', 'jquery', 'fixed-data-table-2', 'google-maps-react', 'lodash', 'react', 'react-dom', 'react-bootstrap'],
  },
  output: {
    // The build folder.
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
    // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
    // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
    // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    // devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
    //   path
    //     .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
    //     .replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      // @remove-on-eject-begin
      // Resolve Babel runtime relative to react-scripts.
      // It usually still works on npm 3 without this but it would be
      // unfortunate to rely on, as react-scripts could be symlinked,
      // and thus babel-runtime might not be resolvable from the source.
      'babel-runtime': path.dirname(
        require.resolve('babel-runtime/package.json')
      ),
      // @remove-on-eject-end
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    moduleExtensions: ["-loader"]
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // TODO: Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      // We are waiting for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2176.
      // { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
      // {
      //   test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      //   enforce: 'pre',
      //   use: [
      //     {
      //       options: {
      //         formatter: eslintFormatter,
      //         // @remove-on-eject-begin
      //         // TODO: consider separate config for production,
      //         // e.g. to enable no-console and no-debugger only in production.
      //         baseConfig: {
      //           extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app')],
      //         },
      //         ignore: false,
      //         useEslintrc: false,
      //         // @remove-on-eject-end
      //       },
      //       loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
      //     },
      //   ],
      //   include: paths.appSrc,
      // },
      // ** ADDING/UPDATING LOADERS **
      // The "file" loader handles all assets unless explicitly excluded.
      // The `exclude` list *must* be updated with every change to loader extensions.
      // When adding a new loader, you must add its `test`
      // as a new entry in the `exclude` list in the "file" loader.

      // "file" loader makes sure those assets end up in the `build` folder.
      // When you `import` an asset, you get its filename.
      {
        exclude: [
          /\.html$/,
          /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          /\.css$/,
          /\.json$/,
          /\.bmp$/,
          /\.gif$/,
          /\.jpe?g$/,
          /\.png$/,
          /\.scss$/,
          /\.yml$/,
        ],
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
      // "url" loader works just like "file" loader but it also embeds
      // assets smaller than specified size as data URLs to avoid requests.
      {
        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
      // Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        exclude: /\le.min.js$/,
        options: {
          // @remove-on-eject-begin
          babelrc: true,
          presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015'), require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'), require.resolve('babel-preset-stage-2'), require.resolve('babel-preset-stage-1'), require.resolve('babel-preset-stage-3')],
          plugins: [require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-class-properties'), require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions')],
          // @remove-on-eject-end
          compact: true,
          cacheDirectory: false, //important for performance
        },
      },
      // The notation here is somewhat confusing.
      // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
      // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
      // "style" loader normally turns CSS into JS modules injecting <style>,
      // but unlike in development configuration, we do something different.
      // `ExtractTextPlugin` first applies the "postcss" and "css" loaders
      // (second argument), then grabs the result CSS and puts it into a
      // separate file in our build process. This way we actually ship
      // a single CSS file in production instead of JS code injecting <style>
      // tags. If you use code splitting, however, any async bundles will still
      // use the "style" loader inside the async code so CSS from them won't be
      // in the main CSS file.
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          require.resolve('style-loader'),
          {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
            options: {
              // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
              // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: () => [
                require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                autoprefixer({
                  browsers: [
                    '>1%',
                    'last 4 versions',
                    'Firefox ESR',
                    'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                  ],
                  flexbox: 'no-2009',
                }),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
        // loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
        //   Object.assign(
        //     {
        //       fallback: require.resolve('style-loader'),
        //       use: [
        //         {
        //           loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        //           options: {
        //             importLoaders: 1,
        //             minimize: true,
        //             // sourceMap: true,
        //           },
        //         },
        //         {
        //           loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        //           options: {
        //             // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
        //             // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
        //             ident: 'postcss',
        //             plugins: () => [
        //               require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
        //               autoprefixer({
        //                 browsers: [
        //                   '>1%',
        //                   'last 4 versions',
        //                   'Firefox ESR',
        //                   'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
        //                 ],
        //                 flexbox: 'no-2009',
        //               }),
        //             ],
        //           },
        //         },
        //       ],
        //     },
        //     extractTextPluginOptions
        //   )
        // ),
        // Note: this won't work without `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in `plugins`.
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [ require.resolve('style-loader'), require.resolve('css-loader'), require.resolve('sass-loader')]
        // loader : ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
        //   {
        //     fallback: require.resolve('style-loader'),
        //     //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
        //     use: [require.resolve('css-loader'), require.resolve('sass-loader')]
        //   }
        // )
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader : require.resolve('json-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.yml$/,
        loader : [require.resolve('json-loader'), require.resolve('yaml-loader')]
      },
      { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' },
      { test: /bootstrap-sass\/assets\/javascripts\//, loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery'}
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Remember to add the new extension(s) to the "file" loader exclusion list.
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
    // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV was set to production here.
    // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env),
    new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin,
    // Minify the code.
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true, // big one--strip code that will never execute
        warnings: false, // good for prod apps so users can't peek behind curtain
        drop_debugger: true,
        conditionals: true,
        evaluate: true,
        drop_console: true, // strips console statements
        sequences: true,
        booleans: true,
        // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2376
        // Pending further investigation:
        // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
        comparisons: false,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2488
        ascii_only: true,
      },
      // sourceMap: true,
    }),
    // Note: this won't work without ExtractTextPlugin.extract(..) in `loaders`.
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: cssFilename,
    }),
    // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
    // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
    // having to parse `index.html`.
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
    // the HTML & assets that are part of the Webpack build.
    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
      // By default, a cache-busting query parameter is appended to requests
      // used to populate the caches, to ensure the responses are fresh.
      // If a URL is already hashed by Webpack, then there is no concern
      // about it being stale, and the cache-busting can be skipped.
      dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
      filename: 'service-worker.js',
      logger(message) {
        if (message.indexOf('Total precache size is') === 0) {
          // This message occurs for every build and is a bit too noisy.
          return;
        }
        if (message.indexOf('Skipping static resource') === 0) {
          // This message obscures real errors so we ignore it.
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2612
          return;
        }
        console.log(message);
      },
      minify: true,
      // For unknown URLs, fallback to the index page
      navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
      // Ignores URLs starting from /__ (useful for Firebase):
      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2237#issuecomment-302693219
      navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/],
      // Don't precache sourcemaps (they're large) and build asset manifest:
      staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
    }),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendors',
      minChunks: Infinity,
      path: paths.appBuild,
      filename: 'static/js/[name].[hash].js',
    }),
    new CriticalPlugin({
      src: 'index.html',
      inline: true,
      minify: true,
      dest: 'index.html'
    }),
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  },
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide more code? like where is this emulate thing

Comment: @ReiDien Which other files do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question

I was facing this issues because I have ejected from create-react-app by this command **npm run eject**.

So please don't use this command unless it is the only option.

If you want to change some configuration in create-react-app with ejecting it you can use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired)
.

Even after all these changes I was facing this error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '__esModule' of #**

I did solve this issue by adding following polyfill

```
   var defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
  Object.defineProperty = function (exports, name) {
    if (name === '__esModule') {
      exports[name] = true;
      return;
    }
    return defineProperty.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```